# Read specific line from txt file with Python

Tags: python

I've got a txt file of about 720000 rows and what I want to do is to read only one line from this file. The file look like this:

```
0000010010010010010101
0100100101010100001110
0101001001010010100101
1010101010101000000111
...
```

So I try to use this code:

```
 f = open("1.txt", "r")
 line= f.readline(5)
 f.close()
 print line
```

But instead of reading the line number 5, I get as output the first 5 characters of the first line.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline

Answer (score 3):

You can use `linecache` standard library , give the file name and the line number to read as arguments. [[Documentation]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html)

```
fifthline = linecache.getline(`filename`, 5)
```